# CreateStartScripts from groovy to kotlin

Tags: gradle

I am trying to convert CreateStartScripts from Groovy to Kotlin without success

I have tried the following

```
val customUnixStartScript = resources.text.fromFile("gradle/unixStartScript.txt")
tasks.register<CreateStartScripts>("createStartScripts") {
  applicationName="app"
  setUnixStartScriptGenerator(UnixStartScriptGenerator(template=customUnixStartScript))

}
```

But the editor says that named arguments can not be passed. Any idea  ?